# .htaccess rewrite category filters

Tags: .htaccess

I'm wondering if it's possible to write these lines into one

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/sd$ /category.php?category_id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/sd/(.*)$ /category.php?category_id=$1&filters=$2 [L,NC]
```

I've tried with

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/sd/?(.*)$ /category.php?category_id=$1&filters=$2 [L,NC]
```

but it doesn't works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And "it doesn't works" means _what_ exactly?

Comment: Certainly a combined rule will lead to a different result, since in that case the `filter` query argument will _always_ be present, potentially with an empty value. That might very well lead to a change in behavior, depending on how the arguments are evaluated... Question is: _why_ do you want to modify something the works perfectly well and is easy to read, thus to maintain? Shorter is not always better, in contrary...

Comment: I just wanted to know if it's possible to write them into combined rule.

Comment: As said: the result has to differ on close look. If that has effects at runtime depends on your implementation which we do not know (you did not tell us).